# local-storage looping assignment (syntax)

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to save one variable in local-Storage however display it twice in different events `(onload and onclick).`

I thought i did everything fine but when uploaded script onto the server variable is `NaN` instead of value.

Worked on localhost because value of variable was already set to 0.
After few attempts in creating appropriate (at least i thought so) code.

When i change the  value of my variable directly into browser storage,

From `NaN` to `0` rest of script is running fine.

Below is my solution for setting value of variable only once at the beginning. Unfortunately variable changes to 0 with every reload. I looped myself with all those lines.

Need someone with more experience than me and fresh look. I'v changed this code so many times that's why  I'm not actually sure what have I started with.

```
console.log(variable_display); //(1)
if (isNaN(variable_display)===true) {       
    var variable_display=0;
}
localStorage.setItem('variable_display', variable_display);
console.log(variable_display); //(2)
moneybox_display_string = localStorage.getItem('variable_display'); 
console.log(variable_display); //(3)
variable_display= parseFloat(moneybox_display_string);  
console.log(variable_display); (4)

window.onload = start;
function start(){
    document.getElementById("element").innerHTML=variable_display.toFixed(2); 
    console.log(variable_display); //(5)
}
```

This part is assigned to onclick=location.reload() at the bottom of the file. It also adds 0.1 to curent value.

```
console.log(variable_display); //(6)
localStorage.setItem('variable_display', variable_display); 
console.log(variable_display); //(7)
document.getElementById("element").innerHTML=variable_display.toFixed(2);
```

This is how var looks like in those steps:
    On load/reload:

```
(1)  undefined 
(2)  0
(3)  0
(4)  0
(5)  0
```

Those 2 shows after onclick:

```
(6)  0.1
(7)  0.1
```

*Edit:*
Im trying to display variable `onload`, update it `onclick`and display as well.

```
moneybox_display1 = localStorage.getItem('variable_display'); 
variable_display= parseFloat(moneybox_display1);        

function start(){
document.getElementById("element").innerHTML=  variable_display.toFixed(2);
}
localStorage.setItem('variable_display', variable_display); 
document.getElementById("element").innerHTML= variable_display.toFixed(2);
```

Thats the code that would work fine for me if not that value of variable at start is NaN and i can't change it.

Comment: JavaScript variables are not persistent between page reloads. Localstorage is, but you are not using it correctly. In fact, you set the item always in the first snippet.

Comment: your code will do that because the FIRST thing you do with the value of `variable_display` in `localStorage` is set it to 0 - the var named `variable_display` has no magic link to the stored value

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve.